# Removing Ubuntu from Triple Boot Windows OS?

Tags: partitioning

So if I'm currently running a triple boot system of Windows, Xubuntu and Ubuntu would I follow these steps below:

1. Boot Gparted or Ubuntu installation USB/CD and run Gparted.
2. Turn Swap off.
3. Unmount desired partition.
4. Delete desired partition which will result in Unallocated partition.
5. Turn Swap back on.
6. Resize remaining partitions or leave Unallocated partition for a later install.
7. Update Grub.
8. Reboot.

Or did I forget something since I have yet to find a particular topic regarding the removal of Ubuntu from a Windows triple boot system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a live CD or USB for your Linux distribution and start up its partition manager (like Gparted). Find your Windows partition in Gparted's menu—it'll be listed as an NTFS drive.

Right-click on that Windows partition and choose "Delete" from the menu. Your machine may have other Windows-related partitions as well, like "System Reserved" and recovery partitions. If you want, you can delete these as well (but make sure you have recovery discs handy if you're going to delete a recovery partition).

Right-click on your Linux partition and choose "Resize/Move." Resize it so it takes up the rest of the now-free space on your drive.

Click the "Apply All Operations" button in the toolbar to perform the selected tasks. It may give you a warning saying that your computer may not boot, but with most Linux installations this shouldn't be a problem (though if it is, check out this article to fix it). This process may take some time, so let it be!

If you want to clean up, use

```
sudo update-grub
```

to remove them.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but I want to keep Windows and Xubuntu. . .

Comment: So you want to remove Ubuntu, and keep windows and Xubuntu?

Comment: Yes. . . I found a dual boot removal but it wasn't detailed enough so I didn't want to risk having a broken grub.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free tool [**OS un-installer**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769489) to remove an os from your triple boot system. It's easy to use too

To install,

Download/Install OS-Uninstaller in Ubuntu :
either add ‘ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair’ to your Software Sources via the Software Centre or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller
```

OS-Uninstaller can be installed & used from any Ubuntu session (normal session, or live-CD, or live-USB).

PPA packages are available for current versions of Ubuntu.

Use OS-Uninstaller:
Launch it from System->Administration->OS-Uninstaller menu if you use Gnome, or search "os" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the menus...

Comment: No problem! Let us know how it goes

Comment: So in the OS-Uninstaller main options do I format the partition I wish to uninstall and if so what type NTFS or ext3 or. . .  if I uncheck the box will it become Unallocated in Gparted.  I want to install another Distro so I'm almost sure I'm going to have to select "something else" during my next Distro install especially if I'm going to be triple booting again?

Comment: Actually, I googled the OS-Uninstaller, so I'm really sorry, but I cant help you

Comment: So you're not really sure if it will work? 

I canceled uninstall after getting a prompt that if I proceeded my grub files would be removed making my system unbootable, something to that effect. . .

Comment: My friend was using it before as well, but I do not know how that went

Comment: I opened and started to run OS un-installer but cancelled because I didn't quite understand where to install bootloader's so in that process alone when I went to reboot I had a boot error which forced me to repair Grub so now I have Grub with only consist of Windows and Xubuntu, Gnome is not present in Grub but it's still on my system, which boots fine. . .